# Dynamically changing bulma sass variables based on HTML element's class?

Tags: css, sass, bulma

I'm trying to implement a dark and light theme using bulma. The approach I was thinking of is to assign classes to elements dynamically using vue (e.g `.dark-theme` or `.light-theme`) and then use different colours depending on those themes. However, customising the bulma variables based on class selectors in `main.scss` doesn't seem to be working, for example:

```
.dark-theme {
    $primary: /* some colour; */
}
.light-theme {
    $primary: /* some other colour; */
}

@import "~bulma/bulma"
```

The closest question I could find was [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22147959/define-variables-in-sass-based-on-classes) but the solution does not work for me as I need to modify the actual $ variables based on class selectors.

If my approach is stupid and there is a better one please let me know. Note that my bulma setup appears to be working correctly, and changing the variable outside of selectors works as expected.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8796107/how-to-make-changeable-themes-using-css-and-javascript

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37801882/how-to-change-css-root-color-variables-in-javascript

Answer (score 2):

You could compile two css files from the bulma scss files, one for dark mode & one for light mode. Then if dark mode is enabled just reload the page with the dark css file or [use the method in the first comment](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8796160/14950943) to change theme without reloading.

[Here](https://bulma.io/2019/10/15/light-dark-colors/#scheme-variables-for-dark-mode) it suggests swapping the `$scheme-main` & `$scheme-invert` values to generate a dark mode.

I do not have experience with Vue but I know that it would be possible to implement this in JavaScript.